# Add class to all matching hrefs after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, each

I am trying to add the class 'active' to all links that have the same href as the one just clicked.

I have multiple modals with duplicated anchor navigation contained within, so MODAL A has a link to MODAL B, and when I click MODAL B the MODAL B link should have the class 'active' within the newly opened anchor.

The code below doesn't add the class active unless I click that same anchor link again, because I presume the URL is still set to #anchor1 when I click #anchor2 so it still tries to add 'active' to #anchor1.

I need a way of clicking #anchor2 then once the url has updated then search for any other links containing #anchor2

OR clicking on #anchor2 then searches for any other link containing #anchor2 and added the class 'active'

```
jQuery('.featured li a').on( "click", function() {      
    jQuery(".featured li a").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think a quick solution could be moving the content of your first listener into another function called by a `setTimeout` with e.g. 25ms delay

Comment: @seasick - such a simple solution that has worked an absolute treat! Many thanks for that! Add it as an answer so I can select as answered

Comment: although working, my solution is a quick and dirty hack. I'd rather take one of the other solutions where `this.href` is used. Seems to be the cleaner solution to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scope of click-listener function the `window.location.href` is not updated to the new value yet. So you need this:

```
jQuery('.featured li a').on( "click", function() {
    var currentHref = this.href;     
    jQuery(".featured li a").each(function() {
        if (this.href == currentHref) {
            jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
        } else {
            jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over each anchor and turn them off, then use href in the selector to match all of the same anchors and turn them on.

```
jQuery('.featured li a').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('.featured li a').each(function({
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("active");
  });
  jQuery('.featured li a[href="'+this.href+'"]').each(function({
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
jQuery('.featured li a').on( "click", function() {
    //here 'this' referencing anchor that is clicked.
    var clicked_anchor = this;
    jQuery(".featured li a").each(function() {
    //here 'this' referencing current iterating anchor 
    if (this.href == clicked_anchor.href) {
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: if u had any query please ask :)